# Query to show json responses which are public true inside mongoose aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have query like this, in which I try to find average of all ratings linked to specific entity. And then return avg rating as an additional field to entity model. Now I want to filter out only those responses in which public `field` is set to be `true`.

This is how my query looks like:-

```
try {
    const reviews = await Entity.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'reviews',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'entityId',
          as: 'avgRating',
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          avgRating: {
            $avg: {
              $map: {
                input: '$avgRating',
                in: '$$this.rating',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          admin: 0,
          createdAt: 0,
          updatedAt: 0,
        },
      },

    ]);
    res.send(reviews);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
```

the query works fine and gives the following response

```
{
    {...},
    {
        "_id": "182ehc02031nd013810wd",
        "public": false,
        "organizations": [
            "icnq03d0-2qidc-cq2c"
        ],        
        "cities": [
            "1234"
        ],
        "name": "test 3",
        "__v": 0,
        "avgRating": 5
     },
     {...},
}
```

I want to add another condition that it should return only those responses in which `public` is set to `true`.

I tried to use `$filter`but did not work.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public` is a document-level field so you need [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) instead of `$filter`:

```
{ $match: { public: true } }
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BCoHdKvA8XQ)

You can also simplify the way you calculate the average:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        avgRating: { $avg: 'avgRating.rating' }
    }
}
```

should work